# Macbook Air trackpad not working smoothly when Tizen IDE (Eclipse) is launched

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, tizen

This is a weird problem. The Tizen IDE made on top of Eclipse CDT makes MacBook Air (2013) trackpad to perform very poor. This happens after few hours of working. But the external mouse is working well. Quitting this application restores smooth movement for trackpad.

Comment: This sounds more suitable for the Tizen [SDK forum](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide) or the Tizen [bug tracker](https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker).

Comment: I was looking if there are any workarounds.